# Showing object instead of db-ref ObjectId when creating a new element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

DB ref is working when:

```
Element.
      findOne({unit: unit_id,).
      populate('unit').
      exec(function(err, element) {
        console.log(element)
      }
```

It will show

```
{
  "unit": {
    "id": "10251179680282633",
    "__v": 0,
  },
  "_id": "50b92eec29921b2531000003",
  "__v": 0,
  "created_at": "2012-11-30T22:10:52.513Z"
}
```

However if I create a new unit and putting my unit in my element and saving,

```
unit = new Unit();
element = new Element()
element.unit = unit;
```

when I do:

```
console.log(element)
```

it returns:

```
{
  "unit": "50b9377d29921b2531000004",
  "_id": "50b9377d29921b2531000005",
  "created_at": "2012-11-30T22:47:25.361Z"
}
```

which is not what I expect because I would like to see unit as an object not as an ID.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected

In your `console.log(element)` example, `element` contains a reference to the ObjectID
It's Mongoose `populate` that does the smarts in getting the `unit` from it's own collection, based on the ID stored in your `element` document.

This page explains this in more detail
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html